# Wordpress plugins - how to change icon?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, icons

[image: plugin of wordpress]

how to change the icon of my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is pretty simple:

1. Create icon image
2. Name it `icon-256x256.png`
3. Place it in assets directory `plugin-name/assets/`
4. Commit the change.

For more detail, check [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/plugin-assets/#plugin-icons).

PS: Please do a Google or Stackoverflow search before posting a question. And always check official documentation before starting work on that OR in case of any issue.